# In indexedDB, how can I tell whether a record was updated or inserted when using objectStore.put?

Tags: indexeddb

When using put() to insert data into a datastore with indexeddb is there a way to know if the record was inserted or updated?

I want to know if the record exists.  Either way I am going to insert/update the data.  This is made difficult by the async api.

Comment: Why would you want to know that? My tought is if you want to update something, you will have to retrieve it first. In that case you know when you are updating or inserting

Answer (score 3):

Another pattern is using cursor. You save cpu time a little bit.

```
req = objStore.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(key))
req.onsuccess = function(ev) {
  var cursor = ev.target.result;
  if (cursor) {
     // do update
    cursor.continue(next_key);
  } else {
     // do create
  }
};
```

I had discussion this issue on http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2012OctDec/0481.html

Comment: for a single record, IDBKeyRange.only(key)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. You could attempt to do `add` first, which would potentially result in a `ConstraintError` error. If you get that error, do `put` instead.

Or just do a `get` first.

Doing get+put always requires two requests. Doing add+put possibly only one (the add).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think I am going to go with the first option or possible use another pattern to accomplish what I am doing.  The async api makes you use different patterns than I am used to.

Answer (score 1):

You can [update via the cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor.update):

```
function insertOrUpdateSomething(db, obj) { 
  var tx = db.transaction('storename','readwrite');
  var store = tx.objectStore('storename');
  store.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(obj.id)).onsuccess = function(event) {
   if(event.target.result) {
     console.log('Updating %s', JSON.stringify(obj));
     event.target.result.update(obj);
   } else {
     console.log('Inserting %s', JSON.stringify(obj));
     event.target.add(obj);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
SaveOrUpdateDate (db,Table,By,Var,Value,CallbackSuccess, CallbackError){
    var data = db.transaction([Table], "readwrite");
    var object = data.objectStore(Table);
    var index = object.index('by_'+By);
    var request = index.get(String(Var));
    request.onsuccess = function () {
        var result = request.result;
        if(typeof result !== 'undefined'){
            result[Var] = Value;
        }else{
            result = new Object();
            result[By] = Var;
            result[Var] = Value;
        }
        var request2 = object.put(result);
        request2.onsuccess = function(e){
            CallbackSuccess();
        };
        request2.onerror = function(e){
            CallbackError();
        };
    }
}
```